# Как найти индекс элемента массива? если известно его значение

Tags: java, массивы

имею простой массив, заполненный случайными числами:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

нахожу в нем минимальное значение:

```
 int min = array[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < min) {
            min = array[i];
        }
    }
```

Скажите, а как я могу вывести в консоль индекс этого значения - min?

Answer (score 3):

Так запоминайте индекс минимума, тогда искать не придётся

```
int imin = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < array[imin]) {
        imin = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Ну или используйте array.indexOf

```
int min = array[0];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{
    if (array[i] < min) {
        min = array[i];
    }
}

int index = ArrayUtils.indexOf(array, min);
```

Comment: а можно пример, пожалуйста, я просто только недавно начал массивы учить

Comment: Добавил пример продолжение вашего

Comment: В вопросе Java,  а у вас что?

Comment: Извините исправил